# How to query two link tables in the same query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join

I have two tables. `device` that can have on `blacklisted_device`. I would like to get the number of device that include specific `user_ids` and in the same request number of `blacklisted_devices` linked.

Here the full sql to try it :

```
CREATE TABLE device (
  device_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id integer,
  updated_at timestamp default current_timestamp
);

CREATE TABLE blacklisted_device (
  blacklisted_id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  device_id integer,
  updated_at timestamp default current_timestamp,
  CONSTRAINT blacklisted_device_device_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (device_id)
      REFERENCES device (device_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
);
INSERT INTO device (user_id)
VALUES (1),(2),(2),(7),(88),(99),(102),(106);

INSERT INTO blacklisted_device (device_id)
VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4);

SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_device
FROM device
WHERE user_id IN (7,88,99);

SELECT COUNT(*) AS blacklisted
FROM blacklisted_device
WHERE device_id IN (SELECT device_id FROM device WHERE user_id IN (7,88,99));
```

As you can see at the end I get the result I want but in two requests. How to get it in one request?

`total_device: 3, blacklisted: 1`

Feel free to make any comment on all the SQL, I probably made few mistakes.

Thanks

Comment: The output you provided is wrong. It should be `blacklisted: 3`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*) AS total_device,
        COUNT(DISTINCT bd.device_id) AS blacklisted
FROM device d
LEFT JOIN blacklisted_device bd
    ON d.device_id = bd.device_id
WHERE d.user_id IN (7,88,99);
```

Comment: Thanks @Lamak that's perfect.